# Unable to locate an lists of elements using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to **scrape** some pages. The exact structure of the part that I want is as follows:

```
<div class="someclasses">
<h3>...</h3> # Not needed
<ul class="ul-class1 ul-class2">
<li id="li1-id" class="li-class1 li-class2">
<div id ="div1-id" class="div-class1 div-class2 ... div-class6">
<div class="div2-class">
    <div class="div3-class">...</div> #Not needed
    <div class="div4-class1 div4-class2 div4-class3">
        <a href="href1" data-control-id="id1" data-control-name="name" id ="a1-id" class="a-class1 a-class2">
            <h3 class="h3-class1 h3-class2 h3-class3">Text1</h3>
        </a></div>
    <div>...</div> # Not needed
</div>
</li>
<li id="li2-id" class="li-class1 li-class2">
<div id ="div2-id" class="div-class1 div-class2 ... div-class6">
<div class="div2-class">
    <div class="div3-class">...</div> #Not needed
    <div class="div4-class1 div4-class2 div4-class3">
        <a href="href2" data-control-id="id2" data-control-name="name" id ="a2-id" class="a-class1 a-class2">
            <h3 class="h3-class1 h3-class2 h3-class3">Text2</h3>
        </a></div>
    <div>...</div> # Not needed
</div>
</li>
# More <li> elements
</ul>
</div>
```

Now what I want is to get the `Texts` as well as the `hrefs`.I have used the naming in above example exactly realistic i.e the same names are also the same in the real webpage. The code that I am currently using is:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='someclasses']/ul[@class='ul-class1']/li[@class='li-class1']")
print(len(elems))
for elem in elems:
    elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("./a[@data-control-name='name']")
    names2.append(elem1.text)
    print(elem1.text)
    hrefs.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

The result of the `print` statement above is `0` so basically the elements are not found. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using only part of the class name... in XPATH you need the full class name...

FYI: With CSS you can use part of the class name...

If you want to use XPATH try:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='someclasses']//li//a")
print(len(elems))
for elem in elems:

    names2.append(elem.text)
    print(elem.text)
    new_href = elem.get_attribute("href")
    print(new_href)
    hrefs.append(new_href)
```

For CSS use: `div.someclasses ul.ul-class1`

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.someclasses ul.ul-class1 li a")
for elem in elems:
    names2.append(elem.text)
    print(elem.text)
    new_href = elem.get_attribute("href")
    print(new_href)
    hrefs.append(new_href)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that u need to give all classes for xpath. There is an error in your code. Need to get rid of elem1 inside the loop and just use `names2.append(elem.text)` instead as elems already is a list of a tags. Your current code gives No such element exception at elem1. Update that and I will accept your answer

Comment: @A.Hamza You are right! I Just copy-pasted your code... sorry about that! glad to help!